# Methods & Parameters

Tags: java, eclipse

Please advise on where I am going wrong. Eclipse isn't showing an error but my answer is not correct.

The task is to write a method sales() that takes a single integer parameter representing the number of additional vacations of that type sold. The method should add this number to the totalSold instance variable and return nothing.

```
public void sales() {       
    int sales = 0; 
    sales = sales + totalSold; 
}
```

Comment: There's no error because it's syntactically correct, but your task was to have the method take in a parameter, which yours does not.

Comment: `int sales = 0;` = create a new variable (not a parameter) of type `int` called "sales" and give it a value of 0. `sales = sales + totalSold;` = `sales += totalSold;` = add totalSold to sales. You have no parameter in your code. You might want to go back to your textbook and review basic syntax and terminology and spend a bit more time thinking about *the meaning* of the code you're actually writing.

Answer (score 1):

You were supposed to add to `totalSold` (not `sales`), and you aren't passing `sales` into the method. Like,

```
public void sales(int sales) {
    this.totalSold += sales; // <-- add sales to totalSold
}
```

Of course, that assumes you have already defined `totalSold`. Make sure you have that

```
private int totalSold = 0;
```

Comment: I would suggest that it's a poor idea to have the parameter name the same as the method name.  Since you're clearly teaching a beginner here, it would be worth avoiding this, both so that there's no confusion over what `sales` is, and so that OP doesn't learn a bad habit.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void sales(int parameterName){

//your code
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This  solve the problem of taking in a single integer parameter. As to solving the question, it should use the following in the method: 
this.totalSold += paramterName

Comment: The explanation should be included to the answer post. Use **Edit** button to do it.